# Finding Similar Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic, intuition

Can we find two sequences:

$$\{a (b^0), a (b^1), a (b^2), a (b^3), \dots, a(b^n)\} \bmod p_1$$

$$\{c (d^0), c (d^1), c (d^2), c (d^3), \dots, c(d^n)\} \bmod p_2$$

that differ by only one number?

**AN EXAMPLE**

For example, I start with:

$$\{4^0, 4^1, 4^2, 4^3\} \equiv \{1, 4, 1, 4\} \bmod 5$$

I then take the sum of a similar sequence.  For example, the same sequence modulo 10 is:

$$\{4^0, 4^1, 4^2, 4^3\} \equiv \{1, 4, 6, 4\} \bmod 10$$

Note that the sequences, for length 4, differ by only one number.

Is it possible to find two longer sequences that differs by only one number?

**IF WE CAN GET A LONGER SEQUENCE, WHAT IS IT?  HOW LONG CAN WE MAKE IT?**

Comment: Although this is an interesting question, your general expression is kind of confusing (I'd be lost without an example). Why don't you think it is possible, BTW? Did you try many more?

Comment: @JMCF125:  Thanks for the compliment.  I've tried to find longer sequences, but I'm not really sure how to approach this.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I have a feeling that it may be possible.  One idea I have is to get all the numbers to be the same except for the last one, and use modulus to create a difference.

Comment: I think as it is very general (imagine the amount of options even limiting everything before ten!), maybe you can simply make some tries with random numbers. Otherwise, I suspect this will be easy to answer (unless you made another question like: "is there an infinite amount of these longer sequences? can it be proven?").

Comment: @JMCF125:  I've extended the question to see if we can get a very long sequence.  It's ok if it's an easy answer.  More power to the ones who can solve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you wish,

In the end it is pretty easy:
$$
\forall b, \forall x, \forall y, \forall z : \{b;x;y;z\}\subset \mathbb N\land 
\{y;z\}\not\subset \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty\{b^n\}\cup \{\forall n>b^{x-1}\}\\
\bigcup_{n=0}^x\{b^n\} \equiv
\bigcup_{n=0}^{x-1}\{b^n\} \cup\{y\}\  \text {mod}\ { b^{x-1}-y}\equiv
\bigcup_{n=0}^{x-1}\{b^n\} \cup\{z\}\ \text {mod}\ { b^{x-1}-z}\\
$$

Explaining a little better, all numbers should be naturals (obviously), $y$ and $z$ shouldn't be powers of $b$ (powers of $b$ are already included) nor shall they be greater than $b^x-(b-1)(b^{x-1})=b^{x-1}$ (otherwise, the the exponent in the modulus 
could be reduced - got this from the example below, only using $b=3$). The conclusion (and, in fact, many premises as well) is drawn from mathematical induction.

Here's an example (actually, this is one  of the firsts I used to get to the generalization - from the above, the concretized variables are $b=2;\ x=5;\ y=3; z=2$):
$$
\{2^0; 2^1; 2^2; 2^3; 2^4\} \equiv \{2^0; 2^1; 3; 2^2; 2^3\} \mod{ 2^4-3}\\
\{2^0; 2^1; 2^2; 2^3; 2^4\} \equiv \{2^0; 2^1; 2^2; 5; 2^3\} \mod{ 2^4-5 }\\
$$

Comment: Although you already marked this accepted I'll attempt to generalize for anything (like $m_1, m_2,$ etc. in any position) before tomorrow (if I'm not available, by Monday max). You got me addicted to math again!

Comment: I'm glad to get you interested!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I found the remainders repeat after $y$ and $z$ (seemingly  I haven't confirmed it yet) from $b^{y-1}$; meaning ALL "modulated" sequences are finite. I'll search on and update the answer (eventually). Though first I'll clear up my answer (it has currently more holes than a Swiss cheese).

Comment: Just a note: I used $\bigcup$ because I don't like set-builder notation.